# Implement Search functionality in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to do a search in my table. I am implementing the below logic:

```
    this.props.searchFunc.forEach(function(item) {
      if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(document.getElementById("name").value.toLowerCase().trim()) != -1 &&
             ??
      // here i want to map through `test` array and check if the value is present in the array
    })
```

where in `item.name`, there is a single string.
And in second id where I put `??`, I am having one array, with name `test` and value `["abc","def","ghi"]`.

But I don't understand how to map through an array and check the condition if the string exist there or not. I know the array map function:

```
item.test.map(function(item,id) {
  if(item.toLowerCase().indexOf(document.getElementById("name2").value.toLowerCase().trim()) != -1)
})
```

But the problem is how to check both conditions together, because the search should work only if both conditions are met.

Comment: What are the two conditions?

Comment: When the user will enter values in two different fields, i want to check if the value exist in simple variable named "name" and array "test"..How to apply AND condition between an array and a simple variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter` and `&&`.

Filter will return all items that meet the condition in the callback function.  In your case, you only have one condition.  You can add another condition using the "and" operator: `&&`.  If an item in the array meets both conditions, then it will be included.

```
item.test.filter(function(item, id) {
    if (
        item.toLowerCase().indexOf(document.getElementById("name").value.toLowerCase().trim()) != -1 
        && //some other condition
       ) {
        return item
       }
   })
```

**Edit**

Based on your question, I assume your `searchFunc` looks something like this:

```
const searchFunc = [
  { name: "ABC", test: ["def", "another value"] },
  { name: "ABC", test: ["ghi", "def"] },
  { name: "Not I List", test: ["also not in list"] },
  { name: "ABC", test: ["Does not meet second condition"] }
];
```

And your `test` array:

```
const test = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];
```

It seems like you want to filter items that have a name that equals whatever value `document.getElementById("name").value.toLowerCase().trim())` returns and whose `item.test` array contains the value from `document.getElementById("name2").value.toLowerCase().trim())`.

So, for sake of example, lets save those values in variables that return values `abc` and `def` respectively:

```
const value1 = document.getElementById("name").value.toLowerCase().trim()) // abc
const value2 = document.getElementById("name2").value.toLowerCase().trim()) // def
```

Now we can filter values that both have a `item.name === value1` and whose `item.test` array contains `value2`:

```
const filteredItems = searchFunc.filter(function(item) {
  if (
    item.name.toLocaleLowerCase() === value1 &&
    item.test.indexOf(value2) !== -1
  ) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Here is a snippet:

```js
const test = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];

const value1 = document.getElementById("name").value.toLowerCase().trim() // abc
const value2 = document.getElementById("name2").value.toLowerCase().trim() // def


const searchFunc = [
  { name: "ABC", test: ["def", "another value"] },
  { name: "ABC", test: ["ghi", "def"] },
  { name: "Not I List", test: ["also not in list"] },
  { name: "ABC", test: ["Does not meet second condition"] }
];

const filteredItems = searchFunc.filter(function(item) {
  if (
    item.name.toLocaleLowerCase() === value1 &&
    item.test.indexOf(value2) !== -1
  ) {
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(filteredItems);
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="name" value="abc"> 
 <input type="text" id="name2" value="def">
```

Comment: My second condition is not inside "test" array. It is present in different variable named "name", that is not an array but it just contains a normal string. I know how to check both the conditions individually, i am having confusion in testing the both conditions together.

Comment: The `&&` operators will check against the first condition and if it evaluates as true, then it will check against the second condition.  You would just need to write the expression of your second condition after the `&&`.